# Populate form field with variable set in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, playframework-2.0

I have a form in my play framework project. The user inputs a series of values. I need to store another value in my model as well but I don't want it to be displayed, it has to be hidden. The other complication is that I want this hidden value to store the value of a variable that is determined after the form has been submitted (because it uses one of the values entered by the user to get the variable). Is there a way to do this or would I have to create a separate model to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want it to be displayed, it has to be hidden.

Option 1: either bind the value to the element using $.data() if you use jQuery which is the cleanest approach to do this

Option 2: Put this value as text in a `<input type='hidden' disabled='disabled'>`. Not recommended

> The other complication is that I want this hidden value to store the value of a variable that is determined after the form has been submitted

Update the value on the success handler of ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    url: '#wherever',
    data: $('#yourform').serialize();
    success: function(e) { // update the original value from response here },
    error: function(e) { // something bad occured, handle it!! }
});
```